# Combining two 8 bit registers to form a 16 bit variable

Tags: assembly, atmega, atmel, 8-bit

I have been tasked with implementing an addition algorithm that can deal with 16 bit numbers. I am using the atmega328p which is an 8 bit microcontroller. The brief says: " use "global variables" to store the inputs and outputs of the addition algorithm". I am unsure how to define these global variables given that they need to store 16 bit values and this is an 8 bit microcontroller. Any advice or relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have implemented the algorithm (I'm not asking for help with the algorithm) and am for now using sets of 2 registers to store the values for each input or output in the form of one register being the high byte and one register being the low byte.

Comment: A variable is basically nothing more than a convenient way in higher-level languages to refer to a location in memory. In C, for example, if you define a variable like `int v;`, then the compiler reserves a few bytes in memory for the variable. Most assemblers have directives to basically do the same, reserve a few bytes of memory for data. If you have a label to that memory you can use the label to access the memory.

Comment: Have you checked the databook? Section 7.4 'General Purpose Register File' and section 16.3 'Accessing 16-bit Registers' offer good clues on how 8 bit registers are labeled and used for 16 bit arithmetic. Your memory assignments can mimic these.

Comment: No need to use 2 registers because you will first add the less significant bytes, then the most significant bytes (with the carry). The useful thing to know is the endianness of the 16 bit data...

Comment: If you have to write a working program, then it depends on the assembler you are using.